# Compare ID numbers with revision numbers in two files and if the rev# for File A is less than File B replace the line with the newer rev#?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a rules file. In each line there a sid:number with a rev:number.

I want to compare this file with with an updated file however, not all line will be updated.

If one of the lines with the same sid:number has a higher rev:number I need it replaced with the higher rev:number.

This is kind of where I'm at so far

```
grep -oP "sid:[0-9]{0,11}; rev:[0-9]{0,3}" all_rules.rules | 
  while read line; do 
    if grep -q "$line" /home/path/update_rules.rules; then 
      echo updated; 
    else 
      echo > /dev/null; 
    fi
  done
```

This is an example of an all.rules file:

```
alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET                 
TROJAN CopyKittens? Matryoshka DNS Lookup 1 (winupdate64 . com)"; 
content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; 
content:"|0b|winupdate64|03|com|00|"; nocase; distance:0; fast_pattern; 
reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/Operation_Wilted_Tulip.pdf; classtype:trojan-
activity; sid:2024495; rev:1;)
alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET 
TROJAN CopyKittens? Matryoshka DNS Lookup 2 (twiter-statics . info)"; 
content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; 
content:"|0e|twiter|2d|statics|04|info|00|"; nocase; distance:0; 
fast_pattern; reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/Operation_Wilted_Tulip.pdf; 
reference:md5,752240cddda5acb5e8d026cef82e2b54; classtype:trojan-
activity; sid:2024496; rev:1;)
alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET TROJAN CopyKittens? Cobalt 
Strike DNS Lookup (cloudflare-analyse . com)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 
00 00 00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; 
content:"|12|cloudflare|2d|analyse|03|com|00|"; nocase; distance:0; 
fast_pattern; threshold:type limit, track by_src, count 1, seconds 60; 
reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/Operation_Wilted_Tulip.pdf; 
reference:md5,752240cddda5acb5e8d026cef82e2b54; classtype:trojan-
activity; sid:2024497; rev:1;)
```

Here is an example of the update.rules:

```
alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"ET TROJAN Revcode 
RAT CnC"; flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; http_method; 
content:".php"; http_uri; content:"keyauth="; http_client_body; 
fast_pattern; depth:8; content:"&key="; http_client_body; distance:0; 
content:"&uid="; http_client_body; distance:0; content:!"Referer|3a|"; 
http_header; content:"WinHttpRequest"; http_header; metadata: 
former_category TROJAN; reference:md5,3f652d9bc17a4be3c0e497ea19848344; 
classtype:trojan-activity; sid:2024500; rev:1; metadata:affected_product 
Windows_XP_Vista_7_8_10_Server_32_64_Bit, attack_target Client_Endpoint, 
deployment Perimeter, signature_severity Major, created_at 2017_07_27, 
performance_impact Moderate, updated_at 2017_07_27;)
alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET TROJAN CopyKittens? Matryoshka 
DNS Lookup 1 (winupdate64 . com)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 
00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|0b|winupdate64|03|com|00|"; nocase; 
distance:0; fast_pattern; reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/Operation_Wilted_Tulip.pdf; classtype:trojan-
activity; sid:2024495; rev:2;)
alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET TROJAN CopyKittens Matryoshka DNS 
Lookup 2 (twiter-statics . info)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 
00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|0e|twiter|2d|statics|04|info|00|"; 
nocase; distance:0; fast_pattern; metadata: former_category TROJAN; 
reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/Operation_Wilted_Tulip.pdf; 
reference:md5,752240cddda5acb5e8d026cef82e2b54; classtype:trojan-activity; 
sid:2024496; rev:2; metadata:affected_product 
Windows_XP_Vista_7_8_10_Server_32_64_Bit, attack_target Client_Endpoint, 
deployment Perimeter, signature_severity Major, created_at 2017_07_25, 
malware_family Matryoshka, performance_impact Moderate, updated_at 
2017_07_25;)
alert udp $HOME_NET any -> any 53 (msg:"ET TROJAN CopyKittens Cobalt Strike 
DNS Lookup (cloudflare-analyse . com)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 
00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|12|cloudflare|2d|analyse|03|com|00|"; 
nocase; distance:0; fast_pattern; threshold:type limit, track by_src, count 
1, seconds 60; metadata: former_category TROJAN; 
reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/07/Operation_Wilted_Tulip.pdf; 
reference:md5,752240cddda5acb5e8d026cef82e2b54; classtype:trojan-activity; 
sid:2024497; rev:2; metadata:affected_product 
Windows_XP_Vista_7_8_10_Server_32_64_Bit, attack_target Client_Endpoint, 
deployment Perimeter, signature_severity Major, created_at 2017_07_25, 
malware_family CobaltStrike, performance_impact Moderate, updated_at 
2017_07_26;)
alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"ET TROJAN 
Win32/BanloadDownloader.XZY Retrieving Payload"; flow:to_server,established; 
content:"GET"; http_method; content:"/sosdoudou_V3/"; http_uri; 
fast_pattern; content:"WinHttp.WinHttpRequest"; http_header; 
content:!"Accept-"; http_header; content:!"Referer|3a 20|"; http_header; 
metadata: former_category TROJAN; 
reference:md5,98376de10118892f0773617da137c2be 
md5,599ea45f5420f948e0836239eb3ce772; classtype:trojan-activity; 
sid:2024499; rev:2; metadata:affected_product 
Windows_XP_Vista_7_8_10_Server_32_64_Bit, attack_target Client_Endpoint, 
deployment Perimeter, signature_severity Major, created_at 2017_07_26, 
malware_family Banload, performance_impact Moderate, updated_at 2017_07_26;)
```

Notice there are three rules that are the same `sid:2024497`,`sid:2024496` and `sid:2024495` however, the update.rules contains the update revisions. I want to replace the older rev inside my all.rules file with the newer rev of the rule in my update.rules.

Comment: Hi, welcome to U&L.  Usual form for a question like this is to post some example input files and the desired output file.  Helps folk clearly understand your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have added what the rules look like in the .rules file. They are Snort rules.

Comment: OK great.  Could do with the input file and the expected output adding for completeness ?

Comment: Please update the question with couple of more input lines and also couple of output lines. It would be great to show both a replaced line and one retained line.

Comment: The input file would just be more of the same type of lines. All snort rules. The only difference is that I am not adding all the lines of the input file, just the ones that are a newer rev number. I need to get my all_rules.rules file only update the lines within it from a list of updated rules from the update_rules.rules

Comment: Whatever it is that you're trying to do, I very strongly recommend **not** piping the first `grep` into `while read line` (why not? abysmally slow. also runs in a sub-shell so can't set vars in the parent shell. possible IFS word-splitting issues).  Instead, use [process substituion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).  e.g. `if grep -q -F <(grep -oP "sid:[0-9]{0,11}; rev:[0-9]{0,3}" all_rules.rules); then ... else ... fi`

Comment: also, whether you think it's necessary or not, providing larger (half a dozen or so lines each) of both input files (all_rules.rules and update_rules.rules) with examples of same sid with both same and different rev in both, AND an example of expected output based on those input files would be of **enormous** use to anyone trying to figure out what you want and work on a solution.  Would also allow all answer to have the same data to work with so they can be checked against each other and the expected output.

Comment: I updated and edited a bit. Let me know if this helps any.

Comment: thanks for the longer samples.  did you add linefeeds or is that how the files really are? your original example just had one very long line.

Answer (score 0):

Made some assumptions to get some kind of answer. Those assumptions being :

1. Unidirectional update : update_rules (or input file 2) is the reference file for what is up to date
2. Reference file is only going to contain the most up to date or at least same revision as the file to be updated (input file 1). **This means, not checking rev (IF2) is actually >= rev IF1 as such. Achtung!**
3. I rely on a diff between IF1 and IF2. Not sure how big (in line count) the difference between both are, this could have an impact

Anyway, enough with the blabla, to the meaty parts

```
#!/bin/bash
cp "$1" "copy_$1" #backup file we're going to change
#then only extract sid + rev (cut -f cols) + sort
#do that for both file and diff them with RCS format > see output of script for example
#and filter to keep only the sid (prob worth testing without grep to see output)
var=($(diff -n <(egrep -oe "sid:[0-9]{0,11}; rev:[0-9]{0,3}" $1|sort -k2) <(egrep -oe "sid:[0-9]{0,11}; rev:[0-9]{0,3}" $2|sort -k 2) | egrep -oe "sid:[0-9]{0,11};" ))
#Now loop over each SID
for i in ${var[@]}; do
  #Extract line number in IF1
  oldline=$(grep -n $i $1|cut -f1 -d:)
  #Extract replacement line in IF2
  newline=$(grep $i $2.txt)
  #awk magic see (note sed was a pain, couldn't get it to work :/) >> https://askubuntu.com/questions/434051/how-to-replace-a-string-on-the-5th-line-of-multiple-text-files
  awk -v nline="$oldline" -v repl="$newline" '(NR==nline){$0=repl}1;' "copy_$1" > "f.tmp" && mv "f.tmp" "copy_$1"
done
#then highlight diff between copy and original // you'll still need to mv "copy_$1" "$1" for it to be applied
diff -n "copy_$1" "$1"
```

Wrap all of that in a script then call it :

`./my_script.sh all_rules.rules /home/path/update_rules.rules`

Comment: I'm not sure where this script went wrong. The sha1sum of the original and the copy are the same after running the script. So there was no update to the all_rules.rules file.
[root]# sha1sum copy_all.rules
d4f10642f1e3932a550581958e64b4aedd75a327  copy_all.rules
[root]# sha1sum all.rules
d4f10642f1e3932a550581958e64b4aedd75a327  all.rules

Comment: Hey David, there was one mistake in my code, hence why it didn't work. Fixed it and should be good (tested with your input) but you need to ensure there's no carriage return in your real file - which appears in your examples, but could be site formatting.

Comment: I still wasn't about to have the old rules replaced. I"ll have to keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in minimal testing:

```
#!/bin/zsh
typeset -A rule sidrev
while read -r line; do
    sid=${${line/*sid:/}/;*/}
    rev=${${line/*rev:/}/;*/}
    if [[ "$rev" -gt "$sidrev[$sid]" ]]; then
        sidrev[$sid]="$rev"
        rule[$sid]="$line"
    fi
done
echo -E ${(F)rule}
```

The script reads snort rules on stdin and on stdout outputs the latest revision of all it has read.

Comment: This issue with this is I'm not using zsh

Comment: My bad; I must have missed the part in the question where it said zsh was not acceptable.

Comment: Oh, no I don't think I mentioned it. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention `perl`, but I'm assuming it's OK to use since you mentioned `awk`, `sed`, and `grep`.  I chose `perl` rather than `awk` mainly because it's much easier to work with multi-level associative arrays (a "Hash-of-Hashes" or "HoH" in `perl` lingo) than in `awk`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

# array used to keep track of the order each sid was first seen,
# so that they can be printed out in the same order.
# Necessary because perl hashes are inherently un-ordered.
my @order=();

# hashed array to contain the highest rev seen of each sid.
my %S = ();

# count of the number of files we've read completely so far.
my $filenum=0;

while(<>) {
  s/^\s*|\s*$//g;  # strip leading and trailing spaces
  if (m/^$/) { $filenum++ if eof; next }; # skip empty lines

  # extract the sid and the rev
  my ($sid, $rev) = $_ =~ (m/^.*; sid:(\d+); rev:(\d+)/) ;

  # store or update an anonymous hash containing the rev and the entire
  # line in the hash, keyed by the sid.
  if (defined($S{$sid})) {
    $S{$sid} = { rev => $rev, line => $_ } if ( ($rev > $S{$sid}->{rev}) );
  } else {
    next if ($filenum); # only store sid if we're still reading the 1st file.
    push @order, $sid;
    $S{$sid} = { rev => $rev, line => $_ };
  };

  $filenum++ if eof;
};

# if you want output sorted by the sid, comment the first of the next
# two lines and uncomment the second
for my $sid (@order) {
#for my $sid (sort keys %S) {
     print $S{$sid}->{line}, "\n";
};
```

Save it as, e.g., `./apply-update.pl` and run it as `./apply-update.pl all.rules update.rules > out.rules`

The output from your new sample input files will be just three lines (with the sids seen in `all.rules`, as updated by `update.rules`, i.e. the "rev:2" rather than "rev:1" versions):

```
alert udp $home_net any -> any 53 (msg:"et trojan copykittens? matryoshka dns lookup 1 (winupdate64 . com)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|0b|winupdate64|03|com|00|"; nocase; distance:0; fast_pattern; reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp- content/uploads/2017/07/operation_wilted_tulip.pdf; classtype:trojan- activity; sid:2024495; rev:2;)
alert udp $home_net any -> any 53 (msg:"et trojan copykittens matryoshka dns lookup 2 (twiter-statics . info)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|0e|twiter|2d|statics|04|info|00|"; nocase; distance:0; fast_pattern; metadata: former_category trojan; reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp- content/uploads/2017/07/operation_wilted_tulip.pdf; reference:md5,752240cddda5acb5e8d026cef82e2b54; classtype:trojan-activity; sid:2024496; rev:2; metadata:affected_product windows_xp_vista_7_8_10_server_32_64_bit, attack_target client_endpoint, deployment perimeter, signature_severity major, created_at 2017_07_25, malware_family matryoshka, performance_impact moderate, updated_at 2017_07_25;)
alert udp $home_net any -> any 53 (msg:"et trojan copykittens cobalt strike dns lookup (cloudflare-analyse . com)"; content:"|01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00|"; depth:10; offset:2; content:"|12|cloudflare|2d|analyse|03|com|00|"; nocase; distance:0; fast_pattern; threshold:type limit, track by_src, count 1, seconds 60; metadata: former_category trojan; reference:url,www.clearskysec.com/wp- content/uploads/2017/07/operation_wilted_tulip.pdf; reference:md5,752240cddda5acb5e8d026cef82e2b54; classtype:trojan-activity; sid:2024497; rev:2; metadata:affected_product windows_xp_vista_7_8_10_server_32_64_bit, attack_target client_endpoint, deployment perimeter, signature_severity major, created_at 2017_07_25, malware_family cobaltstrike, performance_impact moderate, updated_at 2017_07_26;)
```

This will be **many** times faster than any `bash`-based version - shell interpreters just aren't anywhere near as fast at text-processing as `perl` or `awk` or `python`.  A compiled language like `C` would be much faster again, but writing something like this in C would be probably be at least 50 or 60, perhaps even a few hundred, lines of C code, not 15 lines of perl (not counting comments or blank lines).

Comment: BTW, this is the third version of this i wrote, trying different methods.  all worked.  the first two used separate hash arrays to hold all_rules and update_rules, and then compared them during the output stage.  This one uses only one hash, updating it when it saw a newer rev.  much simpler, and can cope with any number of input files.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried this script however, the out.rules contained more rules than my all.rules
    [root]# wc -l out.rules
    35424 out.rules
    [root]# wc -l 20170803_all_golden.rules
    18111 20170803_all_golden.rules
    [root]#wc -l all.rules
    50524 all.rules

Comment: The script makes no distinction between which of the input files its reading, all it really cares about is the order (when it first sees a particular `sid`) and whether the `rev` is greater if it sees a new line with the same `sid`.  This means that if there are new, unseen `sid`s in the update rules, it will add them too.   If that's not the correct behaviour, it's easy enough to fix it so that it adds new `sid`s only from the first file it reads, and only updates from 2nd and subsequent files.

Comment: try it now.  it's important that the all_rules file be the **first** filename argument on the command line.  Only sids first appearing in this file will appear in the output.  sids appearing in 2nd+ filenames will only be used to update existing sids, not store new ones.